# Simple add/remove class isnt working but it makes complete sense

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know there's probably a better approach for this but I'm still learning.
I have a multi-step form with two buttons : save for later AND save & submit.
When the user clicks save for later, I want to add a bootstrap label to an input field on the view page.
If the user clicks Save & Submit, I want to add a different bootstrap label, but for some reason, its not working.
I used similar code on another project but with checkboxes, and it worked fine:

[image: viewall]

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save & Submit" class="sf-right btn btn-success btn-lg" id="saveandsubmitbutton">

<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save for later"  class=" btn btn-primary" id="saveforlaterbutton">



<script>
$("#saveforlaterbutton").click(function() {
$("#status").val("pending");
$("#statuslabel").addClass("label label-warning");
$("#statuslabel").removeClass("label label-primary");
});
</script>



<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#saveandsubmitbutton').click(function(){
$("#status").val("submitted");
$("#statuslabel").addClass("label label-danger");
$("#statuslabel").removeClass("label label-primary");
});
});
</script>
```

Here's the view page:

```
echo "<td><div id='statuslabel' class='label label-primary'>".$res['status']."</div></td>";
```

Comment: so it looks like you are using an `id` to set the `val` and add/remove classes, does each cell have the same `id` in the table?

Comment: In all cases you adding the class label, and then removing the class label, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you need to debug... does the code go into the click? Does it find the element? When you inspect do you see classes that were added/removed? Why are you removing label?  Do you have more than one element with the same id? Also submit buttons submit so if the page submits, they will have the default classes added. Do you cancel the submit action?

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the "label" class immediately after adding it. Try replacing both instances of

```
$("#statuslabel").removeClass("label label-primary");
```

with

```
$("#statuslabel").removeClass("label-primary");
```

Comment: Just saw your update to the question. The `id` attribute should be unique for each element it is on. However `<td><div id='statuslabel'` will generate rows with identical `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a better way to do this but this way was easy for me. I'm still learning loops and everything so if someone can post a better solution with the code I would appreciate it.

What I did was, created another input field and when I save for later or submit, I save a specific label class value to the database and then recall it on the view:

```
<input type="text" readonly value="" class="form-control" id="labelview" name="labelview"  />


<script>
$("#saveforlaterbutton").click(function() {
$("#status").val("pending");
$("#labelview").val("label-warning");
  });
</script>


echo "<td><span class='label ".$res['labelview']."'>".$res['status']."</span></td>";
```

Comment: Isn't "Gentleman" a bit exclusionary? Do you _know_ you're addressing just a group of men?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Ids, use classes or data attributes to identify elements. It seems you have dynamic rows therefore you have to attach events dynamically with each row or capture the event at some global level. For attaching event with each row separately, first select all the buttons (or whichever element you want to attach the event to) using css selectors and then run a foreach loop and attach the event, you will need to track-down other elements of the row for which you can use .closest(). I hope it helps.